# Reverse Proxy with pgadmin and apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, pgadmin-4

I would like to setup the local pgadmin in server mode behind the reverse proxy. The reverse proxy and the pgadmin could be on the same machine. I tried to set up but it always fails.
Here is mypgadmin conf:

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/pgadmin.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/pgadmin.key

  LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
  LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
  WSGIDaemonProcess pgadmin processes=1 threads=25
  WSGIScriptAlias /pgadmin /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgAdmin4.wsgi

  <Directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/>
          WSGIProcessGroup pgadmin
          WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
          <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                  # Apache 2.4
                  Require all granted
          </IfModule>
          <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                  # Apache 2.2
                  Order Deny,Allow
                  Deny from All
                  Allow from 127.0.0.1
                  Allow from ::1
          </IfModule>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and my reverse proxy conf

```
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>

        SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key


    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/reverse_proxy_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/reverse_proxy_access.log combined

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify require
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCACertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"

    ProxyPreserveHost On    

    ProxyPass   /   https://localhost:8080/pgadmin
    ProxyPassReverse    /   https://localhost:8080/pgadmin   

</VirtualHost>
```

The httpd start but when I want to test it with

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://localhost/
```

it give me error 400

but the

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://localhost:8080/pgadmin
```

is working. Where is the problem in my config?

Comment: Error message ``` HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 502 Proxy Error
```

Answer (score 2):

this work for me. I make pgadmin proxy to sub directory (https://localhost/pgadmin)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    DocumentRoot "/var/www"
    
    <Directory "/var/www">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory

    ProxyPass /ws/ ws://0.0.0.0:8888/

    ProxyPass /phpmyadmin/ http://phpmyadmin/

    <Location /pgadmin/>
        ProxyPass http://pgadmin:5050/
        ProxyPassReverse http://pgadmin:5050/

        RequestHeader set X-Script-Name /pgadmin
        RequestHeader set Host $http_host
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This helped for me, specifically putting ProxyPass and ProxyPass Reverse within <Location /pgadmin/> and in my case I used http://localhost:5050/ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with latest version, I think it is fixed this commit Ref: [LINK](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pgadmin4.git;a=commit;h=f401def044c8b47974d58c71ff9e6f71f34ef41d)

Online Docs: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/server_deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

This config works, 
use 0.0.0.0 for pgadmin docker, else use your ip

change port 5050 with your pgadmin port

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName pgadmin.yourdomain.com
 RedirectMatch permanent ^/pgadmin4$ /pgadmin4/
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:5050/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:5050/
 Header edit Location ^/ /pgadmin4/
 Header always set X-Script-Name /pgadmin4
</VirtualHost>
```

Cofigure with SSL, replace yourdomain.com with valid SSL for your domain

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pgadmin.yourdomain.com
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*)$ https://pgadmin.yourdomain.com/$1
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName pgadmin.yourdomain.com

 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem

 RedirectMatch permanent ^/pgadmin4$ /pgadmin4/
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:5050/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:5050/
 Header edit Location ^/ /pgadmin4/
 Header always set X-Script-Name /pgadmin4

</VirtualHost>
```